# Parse multiple JSON objects to normalize the nested sub parts

Tags: python, json

I have incoming JSON files which have elements [a,b,c] and a history element that contains nested JSON with same elements [a,b,c]. There could be multiple nested entries or one or none within history element but below is sample on how data looks. Here is an example:

```
    {

"a": "1",
"b": "2",
"history": [
{
    "a": "11",
"b": "22",
"c": "33"

},
{
    "a": "111",
"b": "222",
"c": "333"

}
],
"c":"3"
}

{   
"a": "a1",
"b": "b1",
"history": [
{
    "a": "a12",
"b": "b12",
"c": "c12"

}
],
"c":"c1"
}
```

I want to normalize this JSON so that everything looks like `{"a": "111", "c": "333", "b": "222"}{"a": "111", "c": "333", "b": "222"}{"a": "1", "c": "3", "b": "2"}`

I built a simplistic script that reads a file and does a json.loads() and reads "histroy" element.

```
import json 
j1 = json.loads(j1) 
if "history" in j1.keys():
    j1_hist = j1["history"] 
    with open('/normalzied_json_output', 'w') as f:
       for i in range(len(j1_hist)):
          f.write(json.dumps(j1_hist[1]))
          j1.pop('history', None)
          f.write(json.dumps(j1))
```

Basically read all of the history into a variable if it exists and open an output file(normalzied_json_output), and read each nested json entry into the output file and extract only [a,b,c] and appends to the same file.

This works at a basic level but I am looking at the possibility of optimizing it. I am expecting a huge volume(100's of thousands) daily and want to know if I can scale this up without too many loops.

Comment: What are `a1`, `b12` and such field values supposed to even mean?

Comment: they are just some characters, no significance as such

Comment: Not sure of the downvote here, I thought I clearly mentioned my issues here. Can someone explain.

Answer (score 0):

First of all JSON operations are expensive in general.

And you are using range which generates a list of numbers, now think of it if your incoming array length is 10000, it will generate all those numbers then iterate over it.

You can remove the if condition to check for the 'history' key and simply use get method like shown below:

```
import json
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    j1= json.load(f)
    with open('/normalzied_json_output', 'w') as f:
        for item in j1.get("history", []):
            f.write(json.dumps(item))

        j1.pop('history', None)
        f.write(json.dumps(j1))
```

Your code by the way doesn't do what you wanted it to do, why are you reading only first index value from history ? why are you using pop inside the loop and writing the whole text again and again inside the loop ?

Comment: oops..that pop is mean to be outside the loop